# How to get top N elements from an Apache Spark RDD for large N

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, rdd

I have an `RDD[(Int, Double)]` (where Int is unique) with around 400 million entries and need to get top N. `rdd.top(N)(Ordering.by(_._2))` works great for small N (tested up to 100,000), but when I need the top 1 million, I run into this error:

```
Total size of serialized results of 5634 tasks (1024.1 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
```

I understand why the error happens (although it is beyond my imagination why 1024 bytes are used to serialize a single pair `(Int, Double)`) and I also understand that I can overcome it by increasing `spark.driver.maxResultSize`, but this solution only works up to a certain N and I cannot know whether it will work or not until the whole job crashes.

How can I get the top N entries efficiently without using `top` or `takeOrdered`, since they both return `Array`s that can get too big for a large N?

Scala solutions are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few solutions to this. The simplest is enabling kyro serialization which will likely reduce the amount of memory required.

Another would be using `sortByKey` followed with `mapPartitionsWithIndex` to get the count of each partition and then figuring out which partitions you need to keep and then working with the resulting RDD (this one is better if you are ok with expressing the rest of your operations on RDDs).

If you need the top n locally in the driver, you could use `sortByKey` and then cache the resulting RDD and use `toLocalIterator`.

Hope that one of these three approaches meets your needs.

Comment: I switched to Kyro serialization but the benefits were questionable. Sorting 400 million items is a long job on my machine so I decided to use `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` instead of `sortByKey` (supposedly sorts faster but I did not perform timing to measure). In the end I decided to dump everything using `saveAsTextFile` because the code that retrieves top N entries manually became too ugly. Once I move to a cluster (soon) I will have to reimplement this and then I can decide on your answer, but right now the job just takes too long for trial-and-error optimization.

Comment: Are you running this on a single machine?

Comment: Yes, for the time being. It takes around 75 minutes to run.